# How to find files and copy to not existing folder in one command?

Tags: directory, find, cp, copy, mkdir

For example:

```
find /usr -type f -name "*.txt" -exec cp -r {} ~/txts/ \;
```

Works fine in case when we have existing directory txts.

As far as I can understand - **cp have no flags** to resolve this case.
Maybe I should use rsync or something else?

Answer (score 2):

Good question, you could try this:
First `cd` into `/usr`, this is because when you use an absolute path (like `/usr` ) with `find` I suspect it will cause `{}` to contain full paths.

```
find . -type f -a -name "*.txt" -a -exec install -D {} ~/texts/{} \;
```

When I run this command, I got the following error message:

> find: ‘./share/doc/google-chrome-stable’: Permission denied

The error message doesn't mean the operation failed overall, it just means `find` wasn't able to run the command on the `./share/doc/google-chrome-stable` directory.
But for me all the other files and their paths were copied and the directory paths were created as needed.

upon further investigation, the cause of the error was

```
% ls -al --directory ./share/doc/google-chrome-stable 
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 Aug 21 12:45 ./share/doc/google-chrome-stable
```

Comment: thank you!
it's really creating all folders which contain any .txt.

" -D  create all leading components of DEST except the last, all components of --target-directory"

But I needed save all files into one folder =)